# Injective Dictionary in .NET

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

Good morning, afternoon or night,

Is there anything like an [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) `Dictionary` in .NET, or at least any way I can force a `Dictionary` to define an injective mapping?

Thank you very much.

Comment: a Dictionary<T,V> is not injective enough for you?

Comment: No... What if I have a `Dictionary<int, int`, say `Test`, and use `Test.Add(1, 1); Test.Add(2,1);`?

Comment: oh well, haven't thought about that...well you can make your own Dictionary and override 'Add', so you can check first if element is already inside or not

Comment: Nice suggestion! I am going to try it!

Comment: Dictionary Add cannot be overridden. Implement `IDictionary<T,V>` using an inner dictionary (or better a custom Injection class using an inner dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this

```
    public class InjectiveDictionary<T, V> : Dictionary<T, V>
    {
        public new void Add(T key, V value)
        {
            if (this.ContainsValue(value))
            {
                throw new Exception("value already used");
            }
            base.Add(key, value);
        }


    public InjectiveDictionary(Dictionary<T, V> dict)
    {
        foreach (var entry in dict)
        {
            this.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }

    public InjectiveDictionary()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is that guaranteed to work the expected with constructors which take as parameters an existing, non-injective dictionary?

Comment: You will have to write the Constructors yourself, there is only one without parameters now.

Comment: keyword `new` is **very** misleading

Comment: you should add  `: Dictionary<T, V>, IDictionary<T, V>`. otherwise other `IDictionary<T, V>` consumers may accidently call the `base.Add` method

Comment: @Tokk: The `new` keyword breaks the Liscov Substitution Principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle.