# Enforcing Different Type Parameters

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

Good morning, afternoon or night,

When implementing, for example, `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` or `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, is there any way I can enforce `TKey` and `TValue` to be different types? I know I can throw an exception in the constructors whenever `typeof(TKey) == typeof(TValue)`, but this doesn't seem neither the most elegant nor the most correct solution...

Thank you very much.

Comment: I usually refrain from comments like these, but why would you ever want to do that? Generics are there to provide, well, *generic* functionality. You can supply a where condition though.

Comment: For example you might have a function overloaded to take `TKey` and `TValue`. If `TKey`==`TValue` it will become ambiguous. Overloading a function in such a way might not be a good idea though.

Comment: Mmh, perhaps I got it, it's because you want to create an injective function with a dictionary --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416390/injective-dictionary-in-net . BTW, identity function is still a function...

Comment: Exactly. If I use indexers and the type parameters are equal, what one would be used?

Comment: I think that's a design issue. You can use an indexer for the `x --> y` direction, but a method for the reverse e.g. `GetXFromY(TValue y)` (or just 2 methods for both directions...)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is anything better. In .net you're limited to a small set of built in constraints, and this is not among them.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the condition explicit with [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/), while keeping the check in the constructor.

```
public class MyDictionary : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public MyDictionary()
    {
        Contract.Requires(typeof(TKey) != typeof(TValue));
    }
}
```